# Get parameter after "#" from url java

Tags: java, android, uri

I have a redirect uri of the form https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=token&expires=5678. I am trying to get the acces token from this url. tried following methods

```
uri.getQueryParameter("access_token"); //will return null since it is not a query param

uri.getFragment(); //will return "access_token=token&expires=5678" so i need to seperate it again.
```

Any direct methods? Pls help

Comment: you can get the indexOf `#` and then create a substring out of the mail uri String

Comment: any other methods pls?

Comment: `getFragment()` _is_ the best method.  Everything after the `#` is considered (by a URL/URI) to be one big value.  If it's delimited or has a special encoding, that's up to the application (and in this case, you) to handle.

Comment: @WilliamPrice yeah. but again I have to split the string to get the token. any other methods? pls

Comment: @deniz No other "magic" methods that automatically know what to do, no.  You will have to write code.

Comment: use `getFragment` you know that token will be in between `access_token=` and `&`...

Comment: @WilliamPrice Okey. I was jus asking you guys to confirm it. Sure i will write the code to split it and get the param Thanks

Comment: @PankajKumar that's a dangerous assumption to make if the input URI might ever contain a query string of its own.

Answer (score 3):

Some one might find this helpful

```
   String queryAfterFragment = uri.getFragment();
   String dummy_url = "http://localhost?" + queryAfterFragment;
   Uri dummy_uri = Uri.parse(dummy_url);
   String access_token = dummy_uri.getQueryParameter("access_token");
```

Works like a charm and easy to use, thank me later :-)

Answer (score 2):

Simple and elegant solution which can get the values which you want:

```
public static Map<String, String> parseUrlFragment (String url) {

    Map<String, String> output = new LinkedHashMap<> ();

    String[] keys = url.split ("&");

    for (String key : keys) {

        String[] values = key.split ("=");
        output.put (values[0], (values.length > 1 ? values[1] : ""));

    }

    return output;

}
```

It's using `LinkedHashMap` to represent values, so it's output:

```
Map<String, String> data = parseUrlFragment (uri.getFragment ());

data.get ("access_token") // token
data.get ("expires") // 5678
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way

```
String str = "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/
                             login_success#access_token=token&expires=5678";
int indexOfHash = str.indexOf("#");
// now you can substring from this
String subStr = str.substring(indexOfHash+1, str.length());
System.out.println(subStr);
// now you can substring from &
String sStr=subStr.substring(0,subStr.indexOf("&"));
System.out.println(sStr);
// now you can get token
String[] arr=sStr.split("=");
System.out.println(arr[0]);
System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

Out put

```
access_token=token&expires=5678
access_token=token
access_token
token
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the String method split(String) with Regex

```
str.split("#|&|=")
```

this splits the string by the passed 3 chars and you get an array with all the splitted parts.

```
String s = 
    "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=token&expires=5678";
final String[] split = s.split("#|&|=");
for (String s1 : split) {
  System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Output:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
access_token
token
expires
5678
```